# python OrderedDict update a list of keys with the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to update a list of keys for an `OrderedDict` with the same `int` value, like

```
for idx in indexes:
    res_dict[idx] = value
```

where `value` is an `int` variable, `indexes` is a `list` of `int`s, which act as keys, `res_dict` is an `OrderedDict`, tried to resolve the above in one line,

```
res_dict[indexes]=value
```

But got the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is a loop or list comprehension the only way(s) to do this update here?

Comment: ***indexes is a list of keys***? and `keys` are what? If there is a list inside `indexes` (which I bet there is), then make sure it is not used as a key; simply because `lists` can't be used as keys.

Comment: @Abdou `indexes` is a list of `int`s, which act as keys in this context

Comment: Well... you could do `res_dict.update((idx, value) for idx in indexes)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OrderedDict (and dict as well) provide the method `update` to update multiple values at once.

The most pythonic manner to do what you want to do is :

```
res_dict.update((idx, value) for idx in indexes)
```

It will keep the original order of your `OrderedDict`.

Comment: The explicit `OrderedDict(...)` is redudant here if `res_dict` is already an `OrderedDict`... existing keys will keep their ordering and any new keys will be inserted as normal...

Answer (score 2):

You could [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) your `OrderedDict` based on a new `OrderedDict` that's created [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys).

The `fromkeys` method allows to give a default value for all the keys, so you don't need any explicit iteration here. And because it uses `OrderedDict`s `fromkeys` it will also keep the order of your `indexes`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> indexes = [1, 2, 3]
>>> value = 2
>>> od = OrderedDict([(0, 10), (1, 10)])
>>> od.update(OrderedDict.fromkeys(indexes, value))  # that's the interesting line
>>> od
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)])
```

Note that in case the `OrderedDict` were empty before the `update` you could also use:

```
>>> od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(indexes, value)
>>> od
OrderedDict([(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)])
```

Comment: in my case, `od` is not empty at the first place, with initialized key:value pairs in place

Comment: okay, then you need the explicit `.update(OrderedDict.fromkeys(indexes, value))`. It was just a thought. :)

Comment: `res_dict.update((idx, value) for idx in indexes)` also retains the order of the `indexes`, right? considering `res_dict` is not empty at the first place

Comment: Yes, that also keeps the order. I just mentioned it because normal `dict.fromkeys` doesn't keep the order. Note that the order of already present items will stay the same no matter which approach you use (except when you delete keys). But if you **also add new keys with `update`** these new keys order depends on the orderedness of the argument passed to `update`. So yes `(idx, value) for idx in indexes` is fine too but `dict.fromkeys(indexes, value)` or `{idx: value for idx in indexes}` aren't.